# How do you associate your melihovv Cart with the model in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-7

I tried using 
Cart::associate('App\Products')->add($id, $name, $price, $quantity);
and I got this error:
call to undefined method Melihovv\Shopping Cart\Shopping Cart::associate

Comment: show some your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `associate` method does not exist in melihovv cart Laravel Package. You should follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/melihovv/laravel-shopping-cart)